# How to delete rows that are duplicate but for one variable while keeping the highest value row?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with 4 variables. There are some rows that are duplicate but for the values on the last variable:

[image]

I only want to extract the one row with the highest value on the last "Total" variable and delete all other rows:

[image]

What is the right code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this helps,

SQL select only rows with max value on a column ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column